# ReactJS How to change from array of arrays to one single array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is that i have that Array:

```
 [
   {
      "_id":"5f32f3d98fe32813803d32e3",
      "StartdateFormatPL":"11.08.2020, 01:30:00",
      "EndDateFormatPL":"11.08.2020, 02:00:00",
      "Hours":[
         {
            "id":"f1dcc-33f8-b32a-3aaa-7bb1b0fcaa6f",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 01:30:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         },
         {
            "id":"d8cfbd6-148a-8e0a-41d4-614d7fa6875",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 01:35:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         },
         {
            "id":"2e71b4-dcb-fb01-1fa0-8eddc5cbd15",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 01:40:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         },
         {
            "id":"cbe26f3-1af2-81a7-3c0b-8ec4be286f15",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 01:45:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         },
         {
            "id":"2475ddf-e6ee-6df7-d22d-860e8a31053",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 01:50:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         },
         {
            "id":"ad23bc-1506-26da-c272-cfca177565a",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 01:55:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         }
      ],
      "__v":0
   },
   {
      "_id":"5f32f60ecee0dd13987cf6a1",
      "StartdateFormatPL":"11.08.2020, 02:00:00",
      "EndDateFormatPL":"11.08.2020, 02:30:00",
      "Hours":[
         {
            "id":"e2bbb4-615e-7aad-0bfd-c7156c5426",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 02:00:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         },
         {
            "id":"fdd2c8-67da-b517-7f85-8e2612f28",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 02:05:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         },
         {
            "id":"5befec6-2a2d-13b2-324d-cd7e86a7626",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 02:10:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         },
         {
            "id":"5d6cb20-80ad-3e38-a7e7-aa5feb88d37",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 02:15:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         },
         {
            "id":"b2c78-358-6176-666-862bacec408",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 02:20:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         },
         {
            "id":"ef3f5e-b60b-18a1-ac13-8542d48dc28f",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 02:25:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         }
      ],
      "__v":0
   }
]
```

This is the response from my API. There are two separate objects which contain `Hours Array`.
In short this is an Array and I wonder how I can convert it to one single array connecting them both into one. I am using ReactJS and I will have many arrays not just only two and I want to connect them into single one..

Summing up [Array] = {... [Array1] ...} {... [Array2] ...] and finnally getting Object of : [{ Array1 + Array2 ....}]

Thanks in advance for help.

Expected Result:

```
"Hours":[
             {
                "id":"f1dcc-33f8-b32a-3aaa-7bb1b0fcaa6f",
                "hour":"11.08.2020, 01:30:00",
                "isBooked":false,
                "isConfirmed":false
             },
             {
                "id":"d8cfbd6-148a-8e0a-41d4-614d7fa6875",
                "hour":"11.08.2020, 01:35:00",
                "isBooked":false,
                "isConfirmed":false
             },
             {
                "id":"2e71b4-dcb-fb01-1fa0-8eddc5cbd15",
                "hour":"11.08.2020, 01:40:00",
                "isBooked":false,
                "isConfirmed":false
             },
             {
                "id":"cbe26f3-1af2-81a7-3c0b-8ec4be286f15",
                "hour":"11.08.2020, 01:45:00",
                "isBooked":false,
                "isConfirmed":false
             },
             {
                "id":"2475ddf-e6ee-6df7-d22d-860e8a31053",
                "hour":"11.08.2020, 01:50:00",
                "isBooked":false,
                "isConfirmed":false
             },
             {
                "id":"ad23bc-1506-26da-c272-cfca177565a",
                "hour":"11.08.2020, 01:55:00",
                "isBooked":false,
                "isConfirmed":false
             },
             {
                "id":"e2bbb4-615e-7aad-0bfd-c7156c5426",
                "hour":"11.08.2020, 02:00:00",
                "isBooked":false,
                "isConfirmed":false
             },
             {
                "id":"fdd2c8-67da-b517-7f85-8e2612f28",
                "hour":"11.08.2020, 02:05:00",
                "isBooked":false,
                "isConfirmed":false
             },
             {
                "id":"5befec6-2a2d-13b2-324d-cd7e86a7626",
                "hour":"11.08.2020, 02:10:00",
                "isBooked":false,
                "isConfirmed":false
             },
             {
                "id":"5d6cb20-80ad-3e38-a7e7-aa5feb88d37",
                "hour":"11.08.2020, 02:15:00",
                "isBooked":false,
                "isConfirmed":false
             },
             {
                "id":"b2c78-358-6176-666-862bacec408",
                "hour":"11.08.2020, 02:20:00",
                "isBooked":false,
                "isConfirmed":false
             },
             {
                "id":"ef3f5e-b60b-18a1-ac13-8542d48dc28f",
                "hour":"11.08.2020, 02:25:00",
                "isBooked":false,
                "isConfirmed":false
             }
          ],
          "__v":0
       }
    ]
```

Comment: Are you looking for this `yourarray.map(a => a.Hours)` ?

Comment: Are you looking for a single array of *just* the `Hours` array objects concat'ed together? It may help to include an example expected result from the example data snippet included.

Comment: i am using it and receive then : [Array(4), Array(4)] and need to convert it to one object containing all Hours possible to book.

Comment: Changed my post and include the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.flatMap(({ Hours }) => Hours);`

Map the data to arrays of `Hours` then flatten.

[flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

> The **`flatMap()`** method first maps each element using a mapping
> function, then flattens the result into a new array. It is identical
> to a `map()` followed by a `flat()` of depth 1, but `flatMap()` is
> often quite useful, as merging both into one method is slightly more
> efficient.

```js
const data = [
  {
    _id: "5f32f3d98fe32813803d32e3",
    StartdateFormatPL: "11.08.2020, 01:30:00",
    EndDateFormatPL: "11.08.2020, 02:00:00",
    Hours: [
      {
        id: "f1dcc-33f8-b32a-3aaa-7bb1b0fcaa6f",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 01:30:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      },
      {
        id: "d8cfbd6-148a-8e0a-41d4-614d7fa6875",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 01:35:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      },
      {
        id: "2e71b4-dcb-fb01-1fa0-8eddc5cbd15",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 01:40:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      },
      {
        id: "cbe26f3-1af2-81a7-3c0b-8ec4be286f15",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 01:45:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      },
      {
        id: "2475ddf-e6ee-6df7-d22d-860e8a31053",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 01:50:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      },
      {
        id: "ad23bc-1506-26da-c272-cfca177565a",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 01:55:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      }
    ],
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: "5f32f60ecee0dd13987cf6a1",
    StartdateFormatPL: "11.08.2020, 02:00:00",
    EndDateFormatPL: "11.08.2020, 02:30:00",
    Hours: [
      {
        id: "e2bbb4-615e-7aad-0bfd-c7156c5426",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 02:00:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      },
      {
        id: "fdd2c8-67da-b517-7f85-8e2612f28",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 02:05:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      },
      {
        id: "5befec6-2a2d-13b2-324d-cd7e86a7626",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 02:10:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      },
      {
        id: "5d6cb20-80ad-3e38-a7e7-aa5feb88d37",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 02:15:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      },
      {
        id: "b2c78-358-6176-666-862bacec408",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 02:20:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      },
      {
        id: "ef3f5e-b60b-18a1-ac13-8542d48dc28f",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 02:25:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      }
    ],
    __v: 0
  }
];

const hours = data.flatMap(({ Hours }) => Hours);

console.log('hours', hours)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that saved my time after couple hours of thinking about that problem :] Appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the map() method

```js
const data = [
  {
    _id: "5f32f3d98fe32813803d32e3",
    StartdateFormatPL: "11.08.2020, 01:30:00",
    EndDateFormatPL: "11.08.2020, 02:00:00",
    Hours: [
      {
        id: "f1dcc-33f8-b32a-3aaa-7bb1b0fcaa6f",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 01:30:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      },
      {
        id: "d8cfbd6-148a-8e0a-41d4-614d7fa6875",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 01:35:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      },
      {
        id: "2e71b4-dcb-fb01-1fa0-8eddc5cbd15",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 01:40:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      },
      {
        id: "cbe26f3-1af2-81a7-3c0b-8ec4be286f15",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 01:45:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      },
      {
        id: "2475ddf-e6ee-6df7-d22d-860e8a31053",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 01:50:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      },
      {
        id: "ad23bc-1506-26da-c272-cfca177565a",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 01:55:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      }
    ],
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: "5f32f60ecee0dd13987cf6a1",
    StartdateFormatPL: "11.08.2020, 02:00:00",
    EndDateFormatPL: "11.08.2020, 02:30:00",
    Hours: [
      {
        id: "e2bbb4-615e-7aad-0bfd-c7156c5426",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 02:00:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      },
      {
        id: "fdd2c8-67da-b517-7f85-8e2612f28",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 02:05:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      },
      {
        id: "5befec6-2a2d-13b2-324d-cd7e86a7626",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 02:10:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      },
      {
        id: "5d6cb20-80ad-3e38-a7e7-aa5feb88d37",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 02:15:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      },
      {
        id: "b2c78-358-6176-666-862bacec408",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 02:20:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      },
      {
        id: "ef3f5e-b60b-18a1-ac13-8542d48dc28f",
        hour: "11.08.2020, 02:25:00",
        isBooked: false,
        isConfirmed: false
      }
    ],
    __v: 0
  }
];

var hours = []
data.map(item =>item.Hours.map(h=>hours.push(h)));
console.log(hours);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: do you know if there is a way to re-utilize the test dataset provided by the questioner and not include it in the answer, it would make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
yourOuterArray.map(obj => obj["Hours"]).flat()
```

The flat array method is new, if your environment does not support it consider using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#flatten) or [Underscore](https://underscorejs.org/#flatten), both have flatten methods.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a reducer would get the job done well - you can even use a simple `push()` if ES6 is not available in your environment

```js
const sample =  [
   {
      "_id":"5f32f3d98fe32813803d32e3",
      "StartdateFormatPL":"11.08.2020, 01:30:00",
      "EndDateFormatPL":"11.08.2020, 02:00:00",
      "Hours":[
         {
            "id":"f1dcc-33f8-b32a-3aaa-7bb1b0fcaa6f",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 01:30:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         },
         {
            "id":"d8cfbd6-148a-8e0a-41d4-614d7fa6875",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 01:35:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         },
         {
            "id":"2e71b4-dcb-fb01-1fa0-8eddc5cbd15",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 01:40:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         },
         {
            "id":"cbe26f3-1af2-81a7-3c0b-8ec4be286f15",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 01:45:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         },
         {
            "id":"2475ddf-e6ee-6df7-d22d-860e8a31053",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 01:50:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         },
         {
            "id":"ad23bc-1506-26da-c272-cfca177565a",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 01:55:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         }
      ],
      "__v":0
   },
   {
      "_id":"5f32f60ecee0dd13987cf6a1",
      "StartdateFormatPL":"11.08.2020, 02:00:00",
      "EndDateFormatPL":"11.08.2020, 02:30:00",
      "Hours":[
         {
            "id":"e2bbb4-615e-7aad-0bfd-c7156c5426",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 02:00:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         },
         {
            "id":"fdd2c8-67da-b517-7f85-8e2612f28",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 02:05:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         },
         {
            "id":"5befec6-2a2d-13b2-324d-cd7e86a7626",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 02:10:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         },
         {
            "id":"5d6cb20-80ad-3e38-a7e7-aa5feb88d37",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 02:15:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         },
         {
            "id":"b2c78-358-6176-666-862bacec408",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 02:20:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         },
         {
            "id":"ef3f5e-b60b-18a1-ac13-8542d48dc28f",
            "hour":"11.08.2020, 02:25:00",
            "isBooked":false,
            "isConfirmed":false
         }
      ],
      "__v":0
   }
]

const result = sample.reduce((accum, entry) => {
  return [
    ...accum,
    ...entry["Hours"]
  ]
}, [])

console.log("Result", result)
```